# How to add dynamically created Checkboxes to Bootstrap row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have added a bootstrap row. Now inside that I want to add checkbox such that checkboxes should display side by side not as line by line as it is now. Here is the HTML.

```
<div class="row" id="ReportRow">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        </div>
</div>
```

and here is the jquery

```
var Reports = "User, Admin, Detail, Summary";
var arrReportscheckBoxItems = Reports.split(',');
var reportscheckBoxhtml = ''
for (var i = 0; i < arrReportscheckBoxItems.length; i++) {
      reportscheckBoxhtml += '<label style="font-weight: 600; color: #00467f !important;"><input type="checkbox" value=' + arrReportscheckBoxItems[i] + '>' + arrReportscheckBoxItems[i] + '</label><br\>';
}
$('#ReportRow').html(reportscheckBoxhtml);
```

Plesae help me to align it properly. Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the `<br\>` tag in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gensytut/)

Just remove the `<br/>` from ur code

```
var Reports = "User, Admin, Detail, Summary";
var arrReportscheckBoxItems = Reports.split(',');
var reportscheckBoxhtml = ''
for (var i = 0; i < arrReportscheckBoxItems.length; i++) {
      reportscheckBoxhtml += '<label style="font-weight: 600; color: #00467f !important;"><input type="checkbox" value=' + arrReportscheckBoxItems[i] + '>' + arrReportscheckBoxItems[i] + '</label>&nbsp;';
}
$('#ReportRow > .col-md-12').html(reportscheckBoxhtml);
```